# How to solve the recurrence T(n) = 4 T (n/2) + n! using master theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have this copy of Master theorem.

> [image]

> where n = size of the problem
> a = number of subproblems in the recursion and a >= 1
> n/b = size of each subproblem
> b > 1, k >= 0 and p is a real number
>
> Then,
> if a > bk, then T(n) = θ(nlogba)
> if a = bk, then
> (a) if p > -1, then T(n) = θ(nlogba logp+1n)
> (b) if p = -1, then T(n) = θ(nlogba loglogn)
> (c) if p < -1, then T(n) = θ(nlogba)
> if a < bk, then
> (a) if p >= 0, then T(n) = θ(nk logpn)
> (b) if p < 0, then T(n) = θ(nk)

I had an MCQ at this [page](https://www.sanfoundry.com/masters-theorem-interview-questions-answers/) which tells that this equation can be solved using master theorem but doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the master theorem you state cannot handle the recurrence
$$ T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n!$$
as $n!$ does not satisfy a polynomial growth bound. In general, the $n!$ is so much bigger than the polynomial rest that it completely dominates, so one will have that $T(n) = \Theta(n!)$.

I'll note that more precise statements of the master theorem handle this. This is for example within [case 3 of the Wikipedia version of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Comment: thankyou for answering